# The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(SmsActivity, int, SmsActivity.SmsReceived) is undefined ??

Tags: java, android, list, listadapter

following code shows an error msg,

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main,mSmsReceiver));
```

error msg: The constructor ArrayAdapter(SmsActivity, int, SmsActivity.SmsReceived) is undefined

full codes is provided below.

My question:

1. How can i fix the error?
2. instead using mSmsReceiver, How/What should i modify to display message in str (below) to ListView

   ```
   str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
   ```

full codes:

```
    import...
    ....   

    public class SmsActivity extends ListActivity {
    private SmsReceived mSmsReceiver;
    public SmsActivity(){
    mSmsReceiver = new SmsReceived();

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main,mSmsReceiver));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    //---method is call when listitem is clicked---
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {edit later});
    }


    private class SmsReceived extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";     
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                          

            }
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

**Sorry, cause i'm really too new with this things, so hopefully you can directly edit in my codes, so that i can see what you try to say. I'm really sorry if it did burden u a lot...

Answer (score 1):

To fix the error, you need the correct object type as a parameter for your adapter. Since you are telling `ArrayAdapter` that its gonna have `String` data type, therefore you must need to provide an array or list-collection object with the type `String`.

Change this:

```
private SmsReceived mSmsReceiver;
```

To this:

```
private String[] mSmsReceiver;
//or
private List<String> mSmsReceiver
```

After changing the data type for **mSmsReceiver**, make sure you do initialize it and fill-in some data before pushing into an **ArrayAdapter**.